# How to filter GET requests with Nginx, keep getting 504 after [GET] "/manager/html"

Tags: http, nginx, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, downtime

I was recently unable to reach my website, receiving a 504 time-out error instead. I checked the logs and found a GET request for /manager/html. I realize this was a failed attempt to reach a control panel but could it be causing the time-out?

I'm using Rails, Unicorn, Nginx, and Ubuntu for my setup and was curious if there's a way to filter GET requests like this or if that would even solve this problem.